# Changing a scope variable in different modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have variable called "name" in the $scope namespace($scope.name).

I modify this variable from different controllers and from different modules. The code is provided below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myModule', 'anotherModule']);

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller( 'MyCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    console.log("My module");
} ]);

myModule.controller( 'MyCtrl2', [ '$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Another hero';
}]);

var anotherModule = angular.module('anotherModule', []);

anotherModule.controller( 'AnotherCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.name = 'Hero';
     console.log("Another Module");
}]);
```

I expect all of the variables to be synced to the same variable. However, each "name" variable has different values at different controllers.

Why? and how can I make all those same variables to be synced?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/3Bc7f/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because they reside in different scopes. To sync $scope.name to the same value, you need to create a service that holds the value.

By default, controllers can't share data, but controllers and services can.

### Update

I updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3Bc7f/6/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myModule', 'anotherModule']);

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['myFactory']);

myModule.controller( 'MyCtrl', [ '$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    console.log(data.name);
} ]);

myModule.controller( 'MyCtrl2', [ '$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    console.log(data.name);
}]);

var anotherModule = angular.module('anotherModule', []);

anotherModule.controller( 'AnotherCtrl', [ '$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    console.log(data.name);
}]);

angular.module('myFactory', [])

    .factory('data',[ function() {

        return {
            'name': 'John Doe'
        };

    }])

;
```

Comment: You mean "directives and services"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use service with two way binding data

```
var storage = { name : 'Tolya'}

myApp.service('srv', function() {
    return storage;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/molo4nik11/3Bc7f/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use $rootScope instead of $scope. Now all scope of name have hero.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myModule', 'anotherModule']);

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller( 'MyCtrl', [ '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.name = 'Superhero';
    console.log("My module");
} ]);

myModule.controller( 'MyCtrl2', [ '$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.name = 'Another hero';
}]);

var anotherModule = angular.module('anotherModule', []);

anotherModule.controller( 'AnotherCtrl', [ '$rootScope', function($rootScope){
     $rootScope.name = 'Hero';
     console.log("Another Module");
}]);
```

Comment: rootScope is not recommended to use for storing these type of data. a service/factory/provider is what he should use.

Comment: yes you're correct. But some of the cases, we need to maintain scope values throughtout the applications, than we can use rootScope. for example maitianing currently logged user name..

Comment: The interpretation of the $rootScope usage might differ. $rootScope is in fact a provider itself but globally available from all scopes. I would not use $rootScope for a storing a logged-in user, I would rather create my own singleton and inject it where needed. It's very easy to abuse $rootScope beacuse it's easy, but soon enough it's bloated with data that is not needed globally.

Comment: @JoakimB Thanks.. Befor I 'm mot aware $rootScope. I did't use in my application. so... But now clear..